# responsive video does not let the text column stay in the same row

Tags: html, css, video

I really need help to place the text column "A natural part of your design process" next to the large responsive video/ It seems as soon as I changed it to be responsive it does not adhere by the bootstrap rules. 
Am I missing something?

Please help I have been trying to fix this for hours now, just can't figure this out.

```
   <div class="row featurette">

      <div class="col-md-9">
          <div id="lightGallery" class="video flex-video widescreen">
            <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/93043225" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

          </div>
           <div class="col-md-2 pull-right">
                  <h1 id="subhead" class="subhead2"> A natural part of your design process.</h1>
          </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
```

here is the fiddle, it looks very different from what i have. I am not sure how to fix it...: 
http://jsfiddle.net/NotJavascriptFriendly/2rTcv/

Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: When you say "it looks very different to what I have" do you mean it looks very different to the website in its current state? If you post a link to the website I can take a look.

Comment: Hey! here is the website: http://www.stepaway.co.uk/ Not sure why the top white logo is acting weird at the beginning of load.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of a play with your site using Chrome Developer Tools.

I think the issue you're having is caused by the following CSS rule:

```
media="screen"
.video {
    margin-left: 20%
}
```

Should be line 404 in your main CSS file.

This causes the video div (col-md-9) to take up more than it's allocated 75% space as it's moved into the center of the page. You might want to find another way of positioning it in order to make room for col-md-2.

Also, your h1 in col-md-2 currently contains no text. Is that intentional?